# "no secrets were provided" when trying to connect to wifi

Tags: wireless, kubuntu

I recently installed kubuntu linux distro on my hp laptop

I am able to see the wifi option ,the wifi is also showing all the available networks ,but i am unable to connect to them whenever i try to connect it says "no secrets were provided" and it disconnects

Comment: Is there a password on the Wifi? Did you enter it? I had a similar problem on my ladptop and it was fixed by not installing a driver (which was back level). Note that for an informed answer, actual distro version,  the relevant parts of `lshw` output, and the kind of Wfi network (WEP/WPA..) would help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with kubuntu the next command fixed my problem which simply changes the regulatory domain

```
sudo iw reg set US
```

just change the  **US**  to your [country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I created a gpg key in KDE and all was good.

I needed the encrypted key wallet set up with a key.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and thank you for the answer! Could please [edit] your answer and provide a bit more details for how to create the GPG key? By adding this information your answer will be much more useful to other users facing the same issue as you did. Thanks!